# Calculate the days before the current days in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to write a function that checks the current day (In the format of Thursday, Friday, Monday), and then displays that day with the last 6 days behind it. For example:

> Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, **Thursday**

> Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, **Wednesday**

The last day being the current day. Hope I explained it more or less clear.

I am using *MomentJs* to get the current day but I haven't managed to get much further than that. I am thinking of maybe using an Array with numbers that equal to the days of the week, but I don't know how to "generate" the other days. I have also thought of using a *for* loop to iterate through the *daysOfWeek* array and log each element until it reaches *currentDay* but then I don't know how to show the days of the week before, as it would only show the days of the current week, for example in the case of Thursday:

> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday

*So Sunday, Saturday, Friday would be missing*

```
function dynamicLabels() {
    let daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

    let currentDay = moment().format('dddd')

    if (daysOfWeek.includes(currentDay)) {

    }

    console.log()


}
```

I know the code is pretty bare bones but I am completely stuck with this, even with the ideas I have mentioned above. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need moment or any other date manipulation for this - all you are after is a re-ordered array of the days. Using straight js - simply pass a day into your function- find its index in the array, create shallow copies of the before and after of that index and concatenate the arrays together. **The selected day will always be last item in teh array.**

Note that the first one (preDays) is actually the portion of the days array AFTER the index of the selected days (but this will be added to the start of the new array - hence 'preDays' name).

Also - I made Sunday the  first day in the array - this matches normal JS date / day naminng conventions.

```js
function dynamicLabels(day) {
    let daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    const dayIndex = daysOfWeek.indexOf(day) + 1;
    const preDays = daysOfWeek.slice(dayIndex);
    const postDays = daysOfWeek.slice(0,dayIndex);
    return preDays.concat(postDays);
    
} 

console.log(dynamicLabels('Thursday'));
//["Friday","Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"];

console.log(dynamicLabels('Monday'));
//["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"];

console.log(dynamicLabels('Wednesday'));
//[ "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```js
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
console.log(days.map((e,i,a)=>a[(new Date().getDay()+i+1)%7]));
```